# Unit testing Adobe AIR JavaScript applications

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, air

I'm building a small JavaScript application in Adobe AIR and I'm looking for some general advice for automated unit testing.

I'd like to be able to run a suite of unit tests from the shell (maybe from a Makefile or similar).

My initial thought was to use something lightweight like [jsUnity](http://jsunity.com/) to run test scripts from within Rhino. I could provide a mock browser environment with env.js. But I'd need stubs for the AIR runtime, which I couldn't find. (I suppose I could write them, but that would be tedious.)

Or is there support for this in AIR already, and I've just missed it?

Any general hints and tips on how to get started would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There is Silk Test, but that could be overkill for you.

http://tracyddd.blogspot.com/

http://tips-testing.blogspot.com/2008/06/silktest-click-html-objects-using.html